# vba to write formula with dynamic cell reference

Tags: vba, formula

```
=BDP(F3& " cusip", "security des")
```

Hi all,

I am trying to write a macro that will insert the above exact formula (with the only difference being the F3 reference cell) into my current active cell.  Below is the actual vba code.

I just need the `"F3"` cell below to reference a variable cell that is determined by Excel/vba every time that I run the macro.

I already have the code to have vba/Excel determine the cell.  Lets just say this variable cell is set as `CName`.  So `CName` houses the cell I would like to use--be it F3, D2 or whatever.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=BDP(F3&"" cusip"", ""security des"")"
```

Can someone help?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the feedback and support!  I figured it out after taking a break and reviewing your ideas!  So by inserting the below will do the trick!  I guess .address (,) is absolutely necessary.

& CName.Address(False, False) &

Thanks again!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the help and select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Cname` variable dynamic if you like:

```
CName = Range("F3").Address
ActiveCell.Formula = "=BDP(" & CName & Chr(34) & " cusip" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "security des" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

If CName is the address of the cell you want to have the formula in, then try something like:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=BDP(" & CName & ""& cusip"", ""security des"")"
```

Comment: Yes, CName is the cell I want to have in the formula, which is dynamic depending on the data.  So CName may be F2, D2 or whatever depending on the data.  I was going down this exact same road as what you have above, but for some reason it does not work, but I do not get an error from vba editor either.  Any idea?  Also, what do you dim CName as?  Thank you.

Comment: Tehscript's answer is more complete and you'll have the CHR(34) that eliminates the need for two quotes.   Dim CName as a string, since the .address returns a string.

Comment: Yeah, thank you to Tehscript, but his script hardcodes F3 into the formula.  Though he did gave me intuition into where by my codes showed no errors but just didn't run.  Thank you to you both!